# Array of prime numbers

Tags: ruby, arrays

I just started getting my hands dirty on ruby and was wondering if someone can help me with this array of primes example. I got the problem off of project Euler, and I want ruby to print an array of prime numbers. However, every time I run the program, it outputs just "0". Can someone shed some light here. Thank you in advance.

```
def prime
    x = 13195
    count = 0
    a = [ ]
    while count < x
        if count % x == 0
            a.push(count)
            a.sort
        end
        count += 1
    end
    puts a
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to test if `13195` is a prime, and you want `a` to keep a list of which numbers divide into `13195`

You need to start `count` at 2, since every number including a prime is divisible by 1. You also need to use `x % count` instead of `count % x`. `x % count` divides x by count and gives you the remainder (which are correctly checking against 0 for).

```
def prime
    x = 13195
    count = 2
    a = [ ]
    while count < x
        if x % count == 0
            a.push(count)
        end
        count += 1
    end
    a
end

arr = prime 
p arr #this will print out a list of numbers which fit into 13195
arr.size == 0 #true if number is a prime, false otherwise
```

Note that there is a lot of optimizations you can do in this algorithm to check if a number is a prime - namely your for loop condition can be:

```
sqrt = Math.sqrt(x)
while count < sqrt
```

you only need to check up to the square root of your number to see if it's a prime

Answer (score 0):

Your array is 0 because `count` is always less than `x`, so dividing `count` by `x`, as the modulus operator does, always returns 0.

Your variable `count` is poorly named; I would call it `f` for factor. And it should be initialized to 2, not 0. Your modulus operator is reversed; it chouls be `x % f` instead of the other way around. And your `while` loop should stop as soon as `f * f > x`, since at that point the remaining `x` must be prime.