# Python: Verifying a prime number

Tags: python

i have written the following code which should check if the entered number is a prime number or not, but there is an issue i couldn't get through:

```
def main():
    n = input("Please enter a number:")
    is_prime(n)

def is_prime(a):
    x = True 
    for i in (2, a):
        while x:
            if a%i == 0:
                x = False
            else:
                x = True

    if x:
        print "prime"
    else:
        print "not prime"

main()
```

If the entered number is not a prime number, it displays "not prime", as it is supposed to. But if the number is a prime number, it doesn't display anything. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Don't use tabs. Use 4 spaces.

Comment: Think about it; if `x` is never set to `False`, when does `while x` end?

Comment: this usage of `input()`  is not a good idea. `int(raw_input())` is better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many efficient ways to test primality (and this isn't one of them). But the loop you wrote can be concisely represented in Python:

```
def is_prime(a):
    return all(a % i for i in xrange(2, a))
```

That is, a is prime if all numbers between 2 and a (not inclusive) give non-zero remainder when divided into a.

Comment: Simple optimization: check 2 and then walk from 3 up by 2. That cuts the number of operations in half.

Comment: @Elazar: `sqrt(a)` is easy `xrange(2, a ** 0.5)` but leads to an error: `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`. Doing `int(a ** 0.5)` leads to a different error: `>>> is_prime(9)
True`. You need to do `int(a ** 0.5) + 1`: `>>> is_prime(9)
False`

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice trick where you only need to iterate up to the square root of the number you are testing for primality:

```
def is_prime(a):
    x = True 
    for i in range (2, int(a**(0.5))+1):
        if a % i == 0:
            x = False
            break

    if x:
        print "prime"
    else:
        print "not prime"
```

You can also optimize in other ways (check if the number is even before you even begin looping). If you are using Python2, use `xrange` instead of `range` etc.

Comment: Nice thinking Martin Konecny!

Comment: Thanks, also your one liner above is very elegant :)

Comment: The code as written won't run: `range` accepts only integer arguments, and `a**0.5` is a float.

Comment: And the +1, too!  +1.

Comment: All of those edits came from my comment an hour before.

Comment: @hughdbrown I answered a similar question over a month ago here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24111021/276949. Nothing was taken from your comments.

Comment: And your answer from over a month ago has exactly the defect I mentioned in my comments if you use `Math.sqrt` without `+ 1`: it does not calculate the factors of 9 correctly. So while I agree you answered a similar question a month ago, your past answer looks more like you picked up uncredited improvements that you put into you own answer in the present. I mean, read your own edit: it has exactly the things I pointed out including things not in your answer a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

After your line `x = False` add a line, at the same level of indentation, `break`. This will cause your function to immediately report a composite number as soon as it finds a factor.

There are better ways to determine if a number is prime or composite. If you are interested, I modestly recommend the essay [*Programming with Prime Numbers*](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have

> ```
> for i in (2, a):
> ```

instead of

> ```
> for i in xrange(2, a):
> ```

secondly, you don't need while x. because if you give it any prime it will stuck there.

3rd is that you don't need to check if you found a non-prime, just print that it is not prime and return.

4th is that you really just need to check until a**(1/2)+1, because any number greater than that can't be small divisor.

here is somehow fixed code:

```
def main():
    n = input("Please enter a number:")
    is_prime(n)

def is_prime(a):
    for i in xrange(2, a**1/2):
        if a%i == 0:
            print "not prime"
            return
        else:
            continue

    print "prime"
    return

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple improvement on your code:

```
def is_prime(a):
    if a % 2 == 0:
        return a == 2
    for i in range (3, int(a ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if a % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Or even:

```
def is_prime(a):
    if a % 2 == 0:
        return a == 2
    else:
        return all(bool(a % i) for i in range (3, int(a ** 0.5) + 1, 2))
```

Then some tests:

```
>>> for i in range(2, 25):
...     print i, is_prime(i)
... 
2 True
3 True
4 False
5 True
6 False
7 True
8 False
9 False
10 False
11 True
12 False
13 True
14 False
15 False
16 False
17 True
18 False
19 True
20 False
21 False
22 False
23 True
24 False
```